# Como Agregar la letra "P" despues de una Vocal

Tags: javascript

Hola tengo que realizar un programa en que dada una frase, la transforme y escriba por consola de manera que después de cada vocal se añade "P" y a continuación se repita la vocal. Ejemplo: Mi casa es amarilla y se transformaría en Ejemplo: Mipi capasapa epes apamaparipillapa.

No se si hacerlo con la frase directamente o convertirla en array primero. Yo había hecho éste código pero no se como seguir, es decir busco las vocales y cuando la encuentro, debería ir añadiendo "P" y la misma vocal y formar la frase.

```
var i;
var cadena = "Hola mundo";
var arreglo = Array.from(cadena);
var arrayM="";
console.log(cadena);
console.log(arreglo); 

for(i=0;i<arreglo.length;i++){
 if(arreglo.indexOf('a')||arreglo.indexOf('e')||arreglo.indexOf('i')||arreglo.indexOf('o')||arreglo.indexOf('u')) != -1){

 arrayM = arrayM + arreglo[i]+'p';
  console.log(arrayM.toString());}


}
```

Si me podeis ayudar, soy nueva en programar con Javascript. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! vamos a hablar en jeringoso??? la idea es correcta.. tu if esta mal implementado... es or entre cada condicion...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aunque ya @gbianchi te ha dado una [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/366059/programa-que-transforme-una-frase-y-despu%c3%a9s-de-cada-vocal-se-a%c3%b1ade-p-y-seguido/366065#366065) muy buena (le encanta Javascript), aquí va otra en la cual no necesitas convertir tu cadena en *array*.

**¿Porqué?**

Porque una cadena es un [*iterable*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Iteration_protocols), por lo tanto podemos recorrer una cadena con un  bucle `for`.

**Condicional**

En cuanto a tu implementación, si que tienes un defecto en la condición que pasas a la sentencia `if`.

Creo que tu idea es la siguiente, pero no la implementaste bien:

```
if(arreglo.indexOf('a') !== -1 || ... || arreglo.indexOf('u') !== -1) { ... }
```

Y en este caso sigue teniendo un problema, ya que el método [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/indexOf) recorre todo el `Array`, y tu ya lo estás recorriendo en tu bucle `for`.

Una forma podría ser plantear las 5 condiciones (1 por cada vocal):

```
if(arreglo[i] === 'a' || ... || arreglo[i] === 'u') { ... }
```

Pero se hace engorroso y podemos mejorarlo un poco.

**Método `includes()`**

Existe un método de los tipo `array` que podríamos usar en este ejercicio, se trata del método [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/includes).

Podemos tener un `array` con las vocales y verificar si el carácter que estamos iterando está incluido en nuestro `array` de vocales, y decidir en consecuencia.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const vocales = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];

//...

if(vocales.includes(arreglo[i])) { ... }
```

Esto hace que el código sea un poco más legible y a la vez nos ahorramos una buena cantidad de *corto-circuitos* con el operador *or* (`||`).

**Código**

Podemos ahora escribir una función, que recibe una cadena como parámetro de entrada y devuelve otra cadena con los cambios señalados.

```js
const frase = "A @gbianchi le fascina Javascript";

function transformarFrase(cadena) {
  const vocales = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
  let salida = '';
  for(let i = 0; i < cadena.length; i++) {
    if(vocales.includes(cadena[i])) {
      salida += cadena[i] + 'p' + cadena[i];
    } else {
      salida += cadena[i];
    }
  }
  return salida;
}

const nuevaFrase = transformarFrase(frase);

console.log(nuevaFrase);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Como puedes observar la frase empieza por una letra 'A' mayúscula, la cual no ha sido incluida en nuestro `array` de vocales. Eso ya es un tema de la especificación del problema, pero que fácilmente se puede solucionar, bien sea agregando las mayúsculas a nuestro `array` o creando otro que contenga las mayúsculas y añadir una condición `else if` para agregar una letra 'P' mayúscula si se pidiera de esa forma.

Comment: Obviamente esta respuesta es mejor y va sobre el lenguaje.. la mia es mas agnostica del algoritmo que intento

Comment: Muchas gracias por las respuestas tan rápidas, me habéis sido de mucha utilidad y me habeis aclarado muchas cosas. Si el if no estaba bien, pero no sabia como ponerlo. Me quedo con la segunda respuesta por que así ahorramos más código; pero la primera respuesta también me ha gustado. Un saludo.

Answer (score 5):

Aca tenemos un par de problemas.

Primero, tu if esta mal.

Todo if se construye igual, y es de la forma condicion o condicion o condicion (la o puede ser reemplazada por una y).

De esta forma, vos no estas escribiendo eso, fijate que pusiste

```
arreglo.indexOf('a')||cadena.indexOf('e')||arreglo.indexOf('i')||cadena.indexOf('o')||arreglo.indexOf('u')) != -1
```

indice de a o indice de e o indice de i (etc) indice de u == -1... o sea, que si esto funcionara, solo esta controlando el ultimo y no todos...

De igual forma, hacer [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/indexOf) tampoco es tu solución, porque esta función retorna el primer índice en el que se puede encontrar un elemento dado en el array, ó retorna -1 si el elemento no esta presente.

Pero, para que hacer eso si vos desarmaste la cadena para fijarte letra por letra que era?

Entonces, mejor hacer arreglo[i] == 'a' etc...

Tambien noto que en el if, intercalas arreglo y cadena.. sobre cual querias hacerlo?

Si buscaramos solo para una vocal, podriamos hacer asi:

```
if(arreglo[i] == 'a'){
    arrayM = arrayM + arreglo[i] + ('p')+ arreglo[i];
}
else{
    arrayM = arrayM + arreglo[i];
}
```

Piensa eso para adentro de tu for.